# Styled posts on facebook wall from android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook sdk to share post on facebook wall. I've successfully shared the post on facebook wall but now could it be styled like? 
[image: facebook wall]

I tried to post like:

```
public boolean updateStatus(String accessToken, String message){  
    String response="";
    try {         
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", "Message here");
        bundle.putString("description", "description here");
        bundle.putString("name", "abc"); //Name of the link
        bundle.putString("link", "www.abc.com");
        bundle.putString("caption", "link capation");
        bundle.putString("picture", "pic url");
        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken);         
        response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");         
        if(response.indexOf("OAuthException") > -1)
        {
            if(mAuthAttempts==0)
            {
                mAuthAttempts++;
                fbAuthAndPost(message);
            }else{
                showToast("OAuthException:");
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {         
        Log.e("MALFORMED URL",""+e.getMessage());
        showToast("MalformedURLException:"+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {         
        Log.e("IOEX",""+e.getMessage());
        showToast("IOException:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```